# Mimas V2 Spartan 6 FPGA flash memory issue

Tags: verilog, fpga, xilinx-ise

I recently bought the FPGA Mimas V2 Spartan 6 FPGA Development Board with DDR SDRAM.

I'm working with xilinx ise 14.7, verilog code, when loading the binary file generated by xilinx in the fpga with tool conmimasv2_configuration_tool_windows.exe the fpga stopped responding, ¿is there any way to reset the flash memory?

windows recognizes the port used by the fpga but does not allow its communication with the.

```
https://numato.com/product/mimas-v2-spartan-6-fpga-development-board-with-ddr-sdram#
https://productdata.numato.com/assets/downloads/fpga/mimasv2/mimasv2_configuration_tool_windows.exe
```

test with sample file

conmimasv2_configuration_tool_windows.exe log

```
    Supported Boards:
Mimas V2(XC6SLX Series)

File selected "mimasv2_sample_bin_file.bin"
Configuration download started...
Unable to open selected port...
```

the communication is from usb (PC) to mini usb (FPGA),
but windows 10 recognizes the fpga on the COM15 port,
the fpga does not turn on the blue light, only the led display and no respond

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention anything about jumpers or switches, so lets check those.

First thing, check the K1 jumper and verify that it has pins 1 and 2 shorted to use the USB as the power source.

Second, check SW7 and verify that it is in position 1.

Try the download operation again.